# Display Flex and position absolute conflict when resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've main element and footer, the main element is `display: flex;` and footer is `position: absolute;` in order to keep it at the bottom, it works fine until resizing ( mobile ).
resize to see the footer conflict!

I'd like to keep to the footer at the bottom on mobile too.

[Live code here](https://jsbin.com/yitowidafa/edit?html,css,output)

```css
#main { display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#main div {
  margin: 10px;
}


footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">

    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try `position: fixed` for footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this issue before and discovered that adding a JavaScript file helped by working out what the screen size is

```
window.addEventListener("load", activateFooter); 
  function activateFooter() {
  adjustFooterSticky();  
  window.addEventListener("resize", adjustFooterCssTopToSticky);
  }

  function adjustFooterSticky() {
    let footer = document.querySelector("#footer");
    let bounding_box = footer.getBoundingClientRect();
    let footerHeight = bounding_box.height;
    let pageHeight = window.innerHeight;
    let aboveFooter = bounding_box.top - TopAttribute(footer);

   if (aboveFooter + footerHeight <= pageHeight) {
    let new_footer_top = pageHeight - (aboveFooter + footerHeight);
    footer.style.top = new_footer_top + "px";
   } 
  else if (aboveFooter + footerHeight > pageHeight) {
    footer.style.top = null;
  }
}

function TopAttribute(htmlElement) {
  let top_string = htmlElement.style.top;
  if (top_string === null || top_string.length === 0) {
   return 0;
  }
  let top_pixels = top_string.substring(0, top_string.length - 2);
  return parseFloat(top_pixels);
}
```

This then located the footer at the bottom of the screen size on any screen size

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use media queries to define place and size your element you should take when when yo switch media here is media query for the mobile

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Smartphones (portrait) ---------- */
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Smartphones (landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 321px){
 /* styles */
}
```

and the following is your example if you resize it to mobile the footer will stay at the bottom

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#main div {
  margin: 10px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  footer {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">

    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
    <div id="container">hel</div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
```

Comment: how isn't work ? may be you should mean in other media

Comment: Try to scroll down on the above snippet!

Comment: check it in your browser there is no obstacle